# Save DataTable to file where column type is list(of KeyValuePair...)

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable, save, keyvaluepair

I am building an SMS ordering service for a restaurant, and am having difficulties accurately saving a Datatable to file, which is later loaded when the program is restarted.

My table contains a column named "MessageHistory" with a type of List(of KeyValuePair) which is being saved as empty.

My table looks like:

```vb
Clients.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {
        New DataColumn("CodedPhoneNumber", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("FriendlyPhoneNumber", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("CurrentOrder", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("OrderHistory", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("TabBalance", GetType(Int32)),
        New DataColumn("MessageHistory", GetType(List(Of KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, String))))})
```

The table is saved to file:

```vb
 Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim formatter As System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
    formatter.Serialize(stream, Clients)

    Dim TableBytes As Byte() = stream.GetBuffer()

    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, TableBytes)
```

Prior to saving, my column with the KeyValuePairs looks something like this (Sorry, don't have enough reputation to embed pictures yet):

[MessageHistory in RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C54CA.jpg)

The file as it is saved, registers that column as:

```xml
<MessageHistory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <KeyValuePairOfDateTimeString />
    <KeyValuePairOfDateTimeString />
    <KeyValuePairOfDateTimeString />
    <KeyValuePairOfDateTimeString />
  </MessageHistory>
```

Since the XML is empty, upon loading the table back into the program it copies every entry as the default Datetime value with nothing else.

So my question is if there is a better way of saving the table, given that the columns are not made simply of 1 dimensional alphanumerical values (All the other columns save and load fine)?

As my program evolves, it's possible that this table will include other array column types.

Thanks Guys

Comment: try this : Clients.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: A DataTable seems an odd choice, whats the reason for that?  There are multiple issues with the serializing code

Comment: You can use a simple POCO object list and use JSON serialization, which will be more efficient.

Comment: @jdweng, that code yielded the same results. 

I chose a datatable over something like an SQL server for simplicity's sake. Since the table can hold all the information with ease, and each spawned SMS conversation can launch a class with a Datarow variable holding all the information that gets reinserted into the main table, it felt like a good fit without needing external applications. I didn't realize the table saving was going to be an issue. I had assumed it would just be a binary byte representation of what was held in RAM. clearly I was wrong.

Comment: Did your results have a schema?  Yes the results may be the same but having the schema and then using the Client.ReadXml("filename") method should give proper results.  The schema will read the data the same as it was saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with. It's not elegant, But it works.

I extract the List(Of KeyValuePair(DateTime,String) into a temporary List of those lists, and save it to a separate file.

```vb
Dim MessageHistory As New List(Of List(Of KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, String)))

    For Each Row In Clients.Rows
        MessageHistory.Add(Row("MessageHistory"))
    Next

    Dim Stream2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    formatter.Serialize(Stream2, MessageHistory)

    Dim HistoryBytes As Byte() = Stream2.GetBuffer
    File.WriteAllBytes(MessageHistoryPath, HistoryBytes)
```

I then load both the original table, and the MessageHistory separately, and reintegrate them.

```vb
        Dim FileBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(ClientFilePath)
        Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(FileBytes)
        Dim formatter As System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()

        Clients = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(stream), DataTable)

        FileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(MessageHistoryPath)
        Dim stream2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream(FileBytes)

        Dim MessageHistory As New List(Of List(Of KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, String)))
        MessageHistory = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(stream2), List(Of List(Of KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, String))))

        For i = 0 To Clients.Rows.Count - 1
            Clients.Rows(i).Item("MessageHistory") = (MessageHistory(i))
        Next
```